# destroying object doesn't remove delegate from invocation list

Tags: c#, object, delegates, destroy

I have a little problem with my objects...
I have an object with one delegate inside to which it subscribe in constructor.
When I destroy this object the invocation list still tell me that it has one subscriber in. and when and create this object again I find two subscriber in (the old that I have destroyed and the new one).
How can I solve this problem and remove the subscriber in the list cleanly?

Here is the code for test:(two button to destroy and create object inside)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    testdelegate thisdelegatetest;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thisdelegatetest = new testdelegate();//create object 
        Timer mytimer = new Timer();//timer to see something BEGIN
        mytimer.Interval = 1000;
        mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mytimer_Tick);
        mytimer.Start();//timer to see something END
    }
    protected void mytimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//each 1second look at the list invocation
        lb_IndelList.Text = "actual subscribers : " + testdelegate.dl_myfunctionthatcopy.GetInvocationList().Count().ToString();
    }
    private void DestroyObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//destroy object
    /*edit*/
        thisdelegatetest.Delete();
        thisdelegatetest = null;//dereferencing for GC
    /*edit*/
    }

    private void CreateObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//create object
        thisdelegatetest = new testdelegate();
    }

}
public class testdelegate
{
    public delegate void del_copysomething(int newvaluetocopy);
    internal static del_copysomething dl_myfunctionthatcopy;
    public int valueforallobject = 0;

    public testdelegate()//ctor
    {
        dl_myfunctionthatcopy += new del_copysomething(copythisint);
    }
    /*edit*/
    public void Delete()
    { 
        dl_myfunctionthatcopy -= new del_copysomething(copythisint);
    }
    /*edit*/
    private void copythisint(int newvalue)
    {
        valueforallobject = newvalue;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Setting a variable to `null` does *not* "destroy" an object. Whatever your mental model is for how objects work in C#, it's wrong.

Comment: Can you please explain the edits you made?

Comment: Please don't edit your question such that *it no longer exhibits the problem and so doesn't make sense*.

Comment: The edited stuff are between /*edit*/ quotes. Pretty clear I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot call the destructor manually, why not implementing the `IDisposable` interface and execute the unregistering in the `Dispose` method?=!

```
public class testdelegate : IDisposable
{
    public delegate void del_copysomething(int newvaluetocopy);
    internal static del_copysomething dl_myfunctionthatcopy;
    public int valueforallobject = 0;

    public testdelegate()//ctor
    {
        dl_myfunctionthatcopy += new del_copysomething(copythisint);
    }
    private void copythisint(int newvalue)
    {
        valueforallobject = newvalue;
        Console.WriteLine("Copied");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        dl_myfunctionthatcopy -= new del_copysomething(copythisint);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

In the `DestroyObject_Click` method you would just call the `Dispose` method:

```
private void DestroyObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   //call Dispose destroy object
    thisdelegatetest.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to all!!

Comment: @Jablonovo I guess it worked, I haven't tested it. Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

```
private void DestroyObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{//destroy object
    thisdelegatetest = null;
}
```

This does not really destroy the object. Objects are "destroyed" (freed) by the garbage collector.

In fact, it **cannot** be marked as collectable because the `static` delegate still references it. Thus, the destructor is never called. You have remove the subscriber manually, e.g. through a public method.

Comment: Except in this case, the object won't be eligible for GC, precisely because there's a delegate still referencing it

Comment: "It takes two garbage collection cycles until the destructor is called." - can you provide a reference to support this statement?

Comment: The statement, "This does not really destroy the object," is a bit misleading. It kind of suggests that it sort-of or somewhat destroys the object. It doesn't destroy it at all.

Comment: Ok, I /*edit*/ the part that I changed. Is that better? So I will need two lines to destroy the object, one for unsubscribe the delegate/events and one to dereference the object for the GC? Is tat right?

Comment: @Enigmativity right, the destructor is called after the first cycle, but the object is freed after the second. I confused something.

Comment: @adjan - There's no guarantee that the destructor is ever called. And objects can be freed during any collection. I think you have some misunderstandings about GC. Can you provide any references to what you're saying? Maybe it's changed since I last looked.

Comment: @Enigmativity I did not say the destructor is guaranteed to be called. And no, dead objects that have a destructor (finalizer) are freed in the next GC generation cycle, after the finalizer was called during the first cycle.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals#what_happens_during_a_garbage_collection

Comment: @adjan - That's not exactly what that link says, but you're close enough.